# WSO2 ESB json-eval($)

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I use property with expression=*json-eval($)* to logging my current body in WSO2 ESB version 6.4.0. It works after every call, but it doesn't work after each of xqueries.

I noticed that it doesn't work after xquery where the output is `</jsonObject>`.

If I have output of xquery like `<objectName></sampleData></objectName>`, my two logs:

```
<log>
   <property name="logInJson" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($)"/>
   <property name="logInXml" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="$body"/>
</log>
```

show the same data.

If I have output of xquery like `<jsonObject></sampleData></jsonObject>` the property `logInXml` shows correct data, but the property `logInJson` shows wrong data (it shows data from last response of call).

Is there any solution to logging every current body in json?

*Edit - example:*

This is my API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test" name="Test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/test">
        <inSequence>
            <xquery key="gov:resources/normalXmlOutput.xq">
                <variable string="myData" name="payload" type="ELEMENT"/>
            </xquery>
            <log>
                <property name="BODY_XML" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="$body"/>
                <property name="BODY_JSON" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($)"/>
            </log>
            <xquery key="gov:resources/jsonObjectOutput.xq">
                <variable string="myData" name="payload" type="ELEMENT"/>
            </xquery>
            <log>
                <property name="BODY_XML" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="$body"/>
                <property name="BODY_JSON" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($)"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

This is first xQuery named *normalXmlOutput.xq*:

```
<x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><![CDATA[
declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/";
declare function xf:normalXmlOutput($payload as xs:string)
    as element(objectName) {
        <objectName>
            <sampleData>{ $payload }</sampleData>
        </objectName>
};
declare variable $payload as xs:string external;
xf:normalXmlOutput($payload)
]]></x>
```

And here is xQuery named *jsonObjectOutput.xq*:

```
<x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><![CDATA[
declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/";
declare function xf:jsonObjectOutput($payload as xs:string)
    as element(jsonObject) {
        <jsonObject>
            <sampleData>{ $payload }</sampleData>
        </jsonObject>
};
declare variable $payload as xs:string external;
xf:jsonObjectOutput($payload)
]]></x>
```

Body of request:

```
{ "payloadRequest": "someValue" }
```

Logs:

```
[2021-02-09 10:48:28,438] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /test/test, MessageID: urn:uuid:20133e1c-f9e4-4f84-953d-4a12274281ac, Direction: request, 
BODY_XML = 
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <objectName>
      <sampleData>someValue</sampleData>
   </objectName>
</soapenv:Body>, 
BODY_JSON = 
{"objectName":{"sampleData":"someValue"}}

[2021-02-09 10:48:28,442] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /test/test, MessageID: urn:uuid:20133e1c-f9e4-4f84-953d-4a12274281ac, Direction: request, 
BODY_XML = 
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <jsonObject>
      <sampleData>someValue</sampleData>
   </jsonObject>
</soapenv:Body>, 
BODY_JSON = 
{ "payloadRequest": "someValue" }
```

As I said, log `$body` in xml shows correct data in both cases, but log `json-eval($)` in JSON shows correct in first case, but in second case data is wrong.

Comment: Can you maybe post the output (wso2carbon.log) of the whole thing? That might help finding the problem. I am especially interested in the different values that get logged using the json-eval statement.

Comment: @ophychius I have added my request body and logs. Last log in JSON shows data from request instead of output from xQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In this case setting the "messageType" to json before logging it should do it. [1]

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```

Internally everything is XML unless specifically specified or returned from a source so setting it like this will make sure the json-eval works.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Generic+Properties

Comment: I tried to set _messageType_ before my log and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add some of the related code around the problem? It's hard to get a clear picture of what's going on.

Comment: I've added related code on the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Not every payload can be wraped by wso2 to proper JSON. The $body - is used to get body from soap message: [read more here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$body) and wso2 internally uses XMLs.

Maybe [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+JSON+Message+Payloads) will help for understand how JSON works in wso2ei.

Comment: After logging I use my ```<jsonObject></sampleData></jsonObject>``` as a body for POST HTTP method. I can't see data in the log, but service I'm calling is receiving ```sampleData:{}``` in the body. So I think the payload is properly wrapped to JSON.